# Is there a way to select by index from a table with a list of integers in KDB

Tags: kdb

This is a table with series of integer in each row:

```
t: flip (enlist `myColumn)!enlist (1 2 3 4 5;6 7 8 9 10;11 12 13 14 15)
```

How can i with a select statement access a particular index for all rows?
This is what i tried:

```
select myColumn'[2] from t
```

What i expect as a result will be a table with

```
myColumn
3
8
13
```

However I get a syntax error. How can one access an element using index position via select stmt?

Thank u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to index in with `@`. Each row is a simple vector, so we can just [index-at](https://code.kx.com/v2/ref/apply/#index-at)

```
q)select myColumn@'2 from t
x
--
3
8
13
```

Answer (score 3):

I think what you want is

```
select myColumn:myColumn[;2] from t
```

As the position in the list is given by the second index of the column.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative if the result is not required as a table:

```
q)@[t;`myColumn]
1  2  3  4  5
6  7  8  9  10
11 12 13 14 15
q)@[t;`myColumn][2]
11 12 13 14 15
q)@[t;`myColumn][;2]
3 8 13
```

You can see that when using `[2]` it takes the third (index of 2) list of values, whereas `[;2]` takes the third value in each individual list, creating the third column's values.